# Can not Remove class in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, lightning-events

```
**Lightning Component1 JS**
```

```
clearAllClickedButtons : function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.uncheckButton",'');

        var clearAllFilters = component.find('uncheckButtons');
        if(clearAllFilters != null){
            for (var i = 0; i < clearAllFilters.length; i++) {
                $A.util.removeClass(clearAllFilters[i], 'active');
            }
        }
        var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:clickEvent");
        var action = component.get("c.viewRecords");

        myEvent.setParams({
            "catchClickedButton": ''
        });
        myEvent.fire();

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.recordList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

```
**Lightning Component2 JS**
```

```
getClickedButtons : function (component, event, helper) {
        var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:clickEvent");
        var clickedButtonList = component.get("v.uncheckButton");
        var clickedEvent = event.getSource();
        var clickedButtonLabel = clickedEvent.get("v.label");
        var action = component.get("c.viewRecords");

        if (clickedButtonList.includes(clickedButtonLabel)) {
            for(var i = clickedButtonList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(clickedButtonList[i] === clickedButtonLabel) {
                    clickedButtonList.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        else{
            clickedButtonList.push(clickedButtonLabel);
        }

        if(clickedEvent.get("v.class") != 'active') {
            clickedEvent.set("v.class", "active");
        } 
        else if(clickedEvent.get("v.class") == 'active'){
            clickedEvent.set("v.class", "");
        }

        myEvent.setParams({
            "catchClickedButton": clickedButtonList
        });
        myEvent.fire();

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.recordList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

```
**clickEvent**
```

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="catchClickedButton" type="List[]" default="" />
</aura:event>
```

In Component2 JS i've added a class `active` to clicked button. And in Lightning Component1 JS i've a button `clear All Filter`, whenever this button is clicked `clearAllClickedButtons` removes the active class from all buttons `(getting with the help of aura:id="uncheckButtons")`. 
but when i fire the `Lightning Component2 JS` again, it is still showing the class `active`.